# What to expect differently in refinance v/s new mortgage in experience

Tags: united-states, mortgage, refinance

I bought a home about 3 years ago and the mortgage process was tiring.  The parties involved were appraiser, banker, underwriter and seller.

Now I am thinking to refinance. Due to the number of parties being less, it should be relatively easy.

Any advice?

Comment: I refinanced through the same company that obtained my original mortgage; that might have made it a little easier, but refinancing was much smoother precisely because there were fewer parties involved. Originally, you were doing *two* things: obtaining a mortgage and transferring the title from the seller to you. Now you are only doing one thing--the mortgage.

Comment: Have you considered working with a mortgage broker?

Answer (score 1):

Refinancing is a lot easier, and  - if you do it right - a lot cheaper.
Many mortgage companies allow you to *reuse* the documents you had to pay for when taking your mortgage to buy the house; for example the official lot location plans, or the title search.
In addition, you don’t have to pay for the recording of the house ownership transfer (but for the lien transfer).

Get a detailed estimate from one company (without committing yet!), and look at each line item. There’s a dozen or more, and many are reducible, avoidable, or negotiable - but you need to do your homework, they won’t come and ask you if you’d like to pay less.